# Reference doesn't respond to HR after agreeing to be a reference

Tags: references

A former manager I requested for a reference check (and who agreed to be called by HR to answer their questions) is not responding to my emails anymore nor to theirs. Should I move on or tell HR to contact him by email/linkedin to set a meeting before calling? Please advise.

Comment: If possible, give HR another reference. The person might be unavailable for reasons entirely unrelated to the reference like being in the hospital or on vacation out of the country, etc.

Comment: It's possible but still I don't want to give out too many references as I might use them somewhere else.. I'll try to wait another week to see what happens (I had 6 interviews for this job - what a waste would it be.. :/)

Comment: She doesn't answer her phone :/

Comment: You can use a reference more than once. They aren't invalid after you've given them for one position.

Comment: Does the new HR company really want to talk to them?  I've had this happen, and usually, they just proceed if the other references are positive; then offer you the job.

Answer (score 6):

If she isn't answering her phone, she may be travelling. Or no longer at that address/company.  Or there may be something else going on, but there is no way we can tell you what.

You can track her down, or you can give the recruiter another reference. Pick one or more.

Comment: I'm new in business and have 2 persons for reference right now from my first job FYI

Comment: Well, rely on the other, or find and talk to the missing person, or ask someone  else if they'd be willing to act as a reference. Or accept that your reference is unresponsive, and since they're volunteers you have no power over that. I see no other possible answers, and only you can judge which ones are worth working on. Nobody ever promised job-hunting was easy...

Comment: Yeah but seriously if someone gives you his word then it means somethings and at least she should appologies not being able to reference anymore. What do you think?

Comment: What I think is irrelevant. For all I know she could.be in the hospital. Your choices are as stated. The world is what it is.

Comment: She could even be dead.

Comment: It's not uncommon for HR departments to sit on an application for weeks then expect a reference immediately.  That could easily coincide with your referee being on holiday, and not checking anythign work-related.  The referee might not have though to let you know abou thte holiday because it was so far into the future.  Every now and then things also happen unusually quickly.

Comment: One of my references gave her contact info at her current company when I asked if I could l list her as a reference. By the time a potential employer contacted her, she was working somewhere else and her contact info had changed. I contacted her directly on LinkedIn to get updated contact info. It was a good chance to reconnect, but also a good reminder to check your references periodically and keep a more "static" way that you can connect with them (LinkedIn, or facebook/personal email if they're okay with it) even if they prefer to have a work email/phone number used on your resume.